# After Microsoft patches in Jan 2018 RSS viewer WebPart stopped working in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

In Dec 2017 RSS viewer webpart was working fine, In Jan 2018 new patches from Microsoft were installed on SharePoint server after that it is giving error in RSS Viewer Webpart

> The requested RSS feed could not be displayed. Please verify the settings and url for this feed. If this problem persists, please contact your administrator

When I checked the ULS logs I found out two below exceptions:

> RssWebPart: Exception handed to HandleRuntimeException.HandleException System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond ***.***.**.**:8089
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
>
> at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception)     -
>
> -- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.BaseXmlDataSource.GetXmlDocument()
>
> at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SingleDataSource.GetXPathNavigatorInternal()
>
> at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SingleDataSource.GetXPathNavigator()
>
> at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.GetXPathNavigator(String viewPath)
>
> at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PrepareAndPerformTransform(Boolean bDeferExecuteTransform)

--

> RssWebPart: Exception handed to HandleRuntimeException.HandleException System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
>
> at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 count)
>
> at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>
> at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer,
>   AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>
> at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean
>   receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>
> at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult
>   lazyResult)
>
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode
>   code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
>
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>
> at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
>
> at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
>   size)
>
> at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
>   size)
>
> at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)     -
>
> -- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.BaseXmlDataSource.GetXmlDocument()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SingleDataSource.GetXPathNavigatorInternal()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SingleDataSource.GetXPathNavigator()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.GetXPathNavigator(String
>   viewPath)
>
> at
>
> Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PrepareAndPerformTransform(Boolean bDeferExecuteTransform)

Below are the patches list which we installed on our server(Windows Server R2 Enterprise)

http://support.microsoft.com/help/4056894
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4055532/security-and-quality-rollup-for-net-framework-3-5-1-4-5-2-4-6-4-6-1-4
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4055269/security-only-update-for-net-framework-3-5-1-4-5-2-4-6-4-6-1-4-6-2-4-7
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4054521/windows-7-update-kb4054521   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4049068/time-zone-changes-in-windows-for-fiji

Is anyone getting the similar kind of issue?

Comment: If you suspect this to be a bug that the patch introduced, your best bet is to report the issue to Microsoft directly.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a test in my SharePoint 2010, I had a rss feed url with https and i got the same error message.

I tried add rss feed url with http and it worked for me.

I read online and found that problem was due to website certificate trust issue , here is an article for your reference:

https://niranjanrao.wordpress.com/2012/07/05/rss-viewer-webpart-error-the-requested-rss-could-not-be-displayed-please-verify-the-settings-and-url-for-this-feed-if-this-problem-persists-please-contact-your-administrator/